# Can't scroll when mouse is on top of fixed div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div but whenever my mouse is on top of it, I can't scroll the `<body>`. Only when the mouse is off can I then scroll the rest of the page. How can I get it so that I can scroll even with my mouse on the fixed div?

*EDIT* Here's a fiddle. Press the first button then put your mouse over the title and try to scroll down. https://jsfiddle.net/qhrmtass/9/

```
.title {
   top:55%;
   position:fixed;
   width:100%;    
   z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using? just done the same thing in safari and it's fine :S

Comment: @sourRaspberri Was just testing in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
.title {
    top: 35%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;    
    z-index: -1;
}
```